# Bootstrap: How to prevent responsive layout below 768px from taking charge?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have responsive view from 768px and disable responsive media queries below it (480px).

Tried setting @screen-xs in [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) to 768px and @screen-xs-max to 0px but it didn't work.

Comment: Try 1px instead of 0.

Comment: I tried 480px for `@screen-sm` in place of 768px in addition to what I tried in Q and it works till the screen is 480px in width so I think if I change `@screen-sm` to 0px , mobile layout will not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in bootstrap they are using sm,xs,lg,and md .based on these classes they are doing media queries.

So, if you don't like to display in tablets and mobile devices . you can use the class hidden-xs, hidden-md etc..both visible and hidden classes are available in bootstrap. You can refer and use.

I hope my solution will be helpful.

Comment: But this would mean that every bootstrap element must have these classes and it would be very tedious to add these in all elements.

Comment: Or use media queries for the particular width you want and define a custom class in that.